# Sort Table Horizontally Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT asunto, MONTH(created_at) as mes, COUNT(turno) as numero
FROM tikets
where id_sucursal = 1 and subasunto = 'Pago' GROUP BY asunto, mes ORDER BY mes ASC
```

Which gives me the results like this:

[image]

I wondered how I could do the consultation to make it work or what I would have to do. Thanks for your attention

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t.asunto, 
       SUM(MONTH(t.created_at) = 2) as month_2,
       SUM(MONTH(t.created_at) = 3) as month_3,
       SUM(MONTH(t.created_at) = 4) as month_4,
       SUM(MONTH(t.created_at) = 5) as month_5
FROM tikets t
WHERE t.id_sucursal = 1 AND t.subasunto = 'Pago' 
GROUP BY asunto;
```

One caution:  When working with months you normally want to take the year into account.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have `PIVOT` function to perform such operation, however, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT t.asunto, 
(SELECT COUNT(turno) FROM tikets WHERE MONTH(created_at) = 2 AND asunto = t.asunto AND id_sucursal = 1 and subasunto = 'Pago') as '2',
(SELECT COUNT(turno) FROM tikets WHERE MONTH(created_at) = 3 AND asunto = t.asunto AND id_sucursal = 1 and subasunto = 'Pago') as '3',
(SELECT COUNT(turno) FROM tikets WHERE MONTH(created_at) = 4 AND asunto = t.asunto AND id_sucursal = 1 and subasunto = 'Pago') as '4',
(SELECT COUNT(turno) FROM tikets WHERE MONTH(created_at) = 5 AND asunto = t.asunto AND id_sucursal = 1 and subasunto = 'Pago') as '5'
FROM tikets t
where t.id_sucursal = 1 and t.subasunto = 'Pago' 
GROUP BY asunto
```